# Generating a Tree Structure From Table

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have an excel document which is like below

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Col1  | Col2  | Col3  |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item1 |       |       |
|       | item2 |       |
|       | item3 |       |
|       |       | item4 |
|       | item5 |       |
| item6 |       |       |
|       | item7 |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

In this table;
 `item1` is the parent of `item2, item3, item5`
`item3` is the parent of `item4`
`item6` is the parent of `item7`

I want to generate a tree structure from this table but I couldn't figure out how to do. How can I do this using C#.

Thanks

Comment: Does that mean than your tree is only 3 levels deepth?

Comment: @DovydasSopa No, It can be more than 3 level

Comment: Then what's the logic of your table? Normally, you would use two columns, where one is `ID`, and second is `ParentId`.

Comment: @DovydasSopa I know. I have Excel documents like this which needs to be imported into SQL with Id and ParentId

Comment: So you need to generate tree structure, **or** import it into SQL database with two columns?

Comment: @DovydasSopa Actually I need to import into SQL but both can work?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a list of parents for all columns. The parent for the first column is the tree root. When you treat a row, append the item to the resecive parent. (It's an error when there is no such parent, foe example if item4 were in column 3.) Add the added item to the list and remove all lower items.

To illustrate:

```
current item                col  pnt    parent list

|       |       |       |               [root]
| item1 |       |       |    1    0     [root, item1]
|       | item2 |       |    2    1     [root, item1, item2]
|       | item3 |       |    2    1     [root, item1, item3]
|       |       | item4 |    3    2     [root, item1, item3, item4]
|       | item5 |       |    2    1     [root, item1, item5]
| item6 |       |       |    1    0     [root, item6]
|       | item7 |       |    2    1     [root, item6, item7]
```

The parent of the current item is `list[pnt]`, where the index of the parent element in the list is `pnt = col - 1`. The recently added element is always the last element in the list.

Comment: It's a clever way.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function `CreateTree` creates a tree starting from a given node as a root. I assumed that input data may be in a jagged array, where each array represents a column from your example table. The node is identified by a `row` in the column, and `depth` being a column from the `columns` jagged array.

```
internal class TreeNode<T> where T : class
{
    public TreeNode(T payload)
    {
        Children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public List<TreeNode<T>> Children { get; }
    public T Payload { get; }
}

public static TreeNode<T> CreateTree<T>(int row, int depth, T[][] columns) where T : class
{
    var node = new TreeNode<T>(columns[depth][row]);
    var maxDepth = columns.GetLength(0) - 1;

    if (depth == maxDepth)
        return new TreeNode<T>(columns[depth][row]);

    var i = row + 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (i >= columns[depth].Length || columns[depth][i] != null)
            break;

        if (columns[depth + 1][i] != null)
        {
            var child = CreateTree(i, depth + 1, columns);
            node.Children.Add(child);
        }

        i++;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Here is the usage based on your example. However, in the example the depth of the tree is 3, this solution works with variable length depth.

```
var depth = 3;
var columns = new string[depth][];

columns = new[]
{
    new string[] {"item1", null, null, null, null, "item6", null}, 
    new string[] {null, "item2", "item3", null, "item5", null, "item7"}, 
    new string[] {null, null, null,"item4", null, null, null}, 
};

var topLevelColumn = columns[0];
var roots = new List<TreeNode<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < topLevelColumn.Length; i++)
{
    if (topLevelColumn[i] != null)
        roots.Add(CreateTree(i, 0, columns));
}
```